# How to look position of number within big matrix?

Tags: excel-formula

I want to search the position of `7` within a NxM matrix. I'm using this formula in Excel 2019.

```
=FIND("7",
            TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,
                     MMULT(ROW(A1:A8),TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1:A1117)))
  ))
```

The part `MMULT(ROW(A1:A8),TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1:A1117)))` is the multiplication of matrices A<sub>8x1</sub> X  B<sub>1x1117</sub> = C<sub>8x117</sub> (this is **8x1117 = 8936 elements**) and will convert in:

```
=FIND("7",TEXTJOIN("",TRUE, {C}))) = 7
```

Where result is `7`.

Now if is M=1118 (**8x118 = 8944 elements**) the result is `#VALUE!`.

```
=FIND("7",TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,MMULT(ROW(A1:A8),TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1:A1118))))) = #VALUE!
```

But if the C matrix has a size of **100x90 = 9000 elements**, I don't receive error

```
=FIND("7",TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,MMULT(ROW(A1:A100),TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1:A90)))))
```

Does this happen because `TEXJOIN()` has limit in number of columns? Which alternative formula can be used?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The limitation is not with the `TEXTJOIN()` function - a cell in Excel cannot contain more than 32,767 characters; your 8,936 element horizontal array contains 6,225 4-digit numbers (so the `TEXTJOIN()` length is 32745), whereas your 9000 element vertical array contains only 5890 4-digit numbers (so its `TEXTJOIN()` length will obviously be shorter, at 32,403 characters...)
The `MATCH()` function returns a _position_ since it takes a 1-dimensional range as argument, not a matrix - for which _position_ is not valid: do you want the row, column, or both?

Comment: The 'size' of the return value is irrelevant - you are trying to circumvent one of Excel's limitations, which is not valid, e.g.  `=LEFT(REPT("a",32768),1)` _would have_ a single character output _if_ it did not disrespect Excel's 32,767 character limitation. For the column result you can use this [array formula](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula) `=AGGREGATE(14,6,(7=MMULT(ROW(A1:A8),TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1:A1118))))*TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1:A1118)),1)`

Comment: Excellent formula. It works but the only issue I found is if the number I'm interested in is repeated, is giving other result and I'd like to get the column of first one. I think the "1" at the end of the formula is to show the first one right? you could try with a small matrix for example in A1:C3 with 2 or 3 number `7` in it.  I've tried like this '=AGGREGATE(14,6,(7=A1:C3)*COLUMN(A1:C3),1)'

Comment: That contradicts your original example, which returned 7, and if 7 _is_ the column # then it is _not_ the first one, since the first 7 occurred in column **1** (in row  7) - kindly edit your question to articulate a requirement **consistent** with your examples

Comment: Actually the first 7 in my first example is in column 7, since first would be first in appeareance considering rows and columns. In my example 7 appears in first row in column 7. The next 7 is in row 7. With `TEXTJOIN()` we get all in a single string concatenating elements of each row in ascending order `e11,e12,...,e1m,e21,...e2m,en1,...,enm`. I hope make sense

Comment: The array formula `=AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(7=MMULT(ROW(A1:A8),TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1:A1117))))*TRANSPOSE(ROW(A1:A1117)),1)` will return 1 as the column # for your original example (it will return 7 if you change the last `1` to `2`)- if that is not what you want then you need to edit your question to include proper sample data

Comment: Thanks for your help. You have gave me ideas with `AGGREGATE()` since I haven't used it before after trying to modify your formula, I didn't get the desired output.  I've opened I new thread for this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77070174/how-to-get-column-of-first-element-in-minor-row