# How to get column of first element in minor row?

Tags: excel-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying (in Excel 2019) to get column of first `1` in a matrix (range) in the minor row.

I currently do this with this formula.

```
=MOD(FIND(1,TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,MyRange))-1,COLUMNS(MyRange))+1
```

But this formula has de disadvantage that if the number of characters joined by `TEXTJOIN()` is more than 32,767 I get `#VALUE!`

For the below example, the first `1` of row 2 is in column 5 and first `1` of row 3 is in column 2 but the minor row is 2, then the answer is `5`

```
=MOD(FIND(1,TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,A2:G5))-1,COLUMNS(A2:G5))+1
```

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5 | C6 | C7 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

Somebody could help me with an alternative formula that handles ranges more than 10k elements?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Another array formula: `=MATCH(1,INDEX(A2:G5,AGGREGATE(15,6,(1/(A2:G5=1))*ROW(1:4),1),),0)`

Comment: Can you post a link to a file with dummy data of that size ? There shouldn't be a limitation, since Excel can handle arrays with 1m items

Comment: Not sure how to link a file for SO. But I've just filled of random numbers between 0 and 9 in a range of 51x50. Then instead to look for "1" I look for letter "k" for example. If I put "k" in any cell within first 50 rows I get correct output. If I put a "k" in row 51 shows error.

Comment: @GerCas - create a publicly accessible file on a cloud-service provider and post the link here - [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyV43.png) image shows there's no issue with a 15k row array (where the first non-zero value is in row 14995)

Comment: @SpectralInstance You can download the test file with link below. Write a `k` in any cell of grey range and result is ok in cell AZ1. Then leave only numbers in A1:AX50 and write a `k` below that range and appears error in AZ1. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gFH1B3PpNA7rR7TiuLf6sixR75ZrXlke/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=117800892717055821762&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Maybe this `=MATCH(1,INDEX(A2:G5,MIN(IF(A2:G5,ROW(A2:G5),9^9))-1,),0)`

Comment: @P.b Thank you. It seems to work but without the `-1` after `9^9))`

Comment: That's because I started the index at row 2. `=MATCH(1,INDEX(A:G,MIN(IF(A2:G5,ROW(A2:G5),9^9)),),0)` this would be better.

Comment: @RasecMalkic Thanks, I'm not sure why you're using `ROW(1:50)` in your formula; I used `ROW(1:4)` in the formula I originally posted because your sample had 4 rows of data - when your data comprise 15,240 rows then you should be using `ROW(1:15240)`

Comment: @SpectralInstance I get it. I was wrong. I've changed to `ROW(1:15240)` and now it works even with letters. You should be put you solutions as answers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=MATCH(1,INDEX(A:G,MIN(IF(A2:G5,ROW(A2:G5),9^9)),),0)`

Will return the column # of the first found row containing `1`.

`IF(A2:G5,ROW(A2:G5),9^9)`
Returns the row number of each value in range `A2:G5` if a value equals `1` (where `1` equals the boolean for TRUE, being used in the IF-formula). If it doesn't equal `1` it returns `9^9` which is a number larger than the last possible row in Excel.
Wrapping this in `MIN()` returns the smallest found row #.

This row # is used inside INDEX, to return the values of that row.
`MATCH` returns the index number of the first found `1` inside the indexed row, whlhich is the result.